# Small Business Starter kit for VS 2010: HRESULT 0x80041FEB

Tags: asp.net, starter-kits

I've just downloaded the MS [Small Business Starter](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/small-business) kit, which is simply a `smallbusiness.vsi` file.  I double clicked this, and got a success message after the install process.  This adds a new web site template, but when I try and add a small business web site to a solution, or simply create a new small business web site, I get an error message with an HRESULT of 0x80041FEB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is a bug in VS2010.

I just encountered this problem and the workaround provided by a member of the Microsoft Web Development Tools team provides this workaround:

2 workaround proposed:

1. Change  the installed template file by:

   a. find the template: e.g. C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual Web Developer\CSharp\club_rtm_v1_cs.zip

   b. Extract the file ProjectName.webproj from the zip file

   c. Edit this file, remove the 1 null byte from it to make it totally empty

   d. Update this file for the zip file (e.g. in windows 7, you can just drag/drop the new file to the zip folder
2. Create the website in VS2008, then open it using VS2010.

SOURCE: http://forums.asp.net/t/1553372.aspx#3838830

I used the first method and it worked for me.